# SpringDataJPA - What does '?1' in the where clause mean in the below query?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

```
@Query(value="select * from author a where a.last_name= ?1",nativeQuery = true)
```

What does ?1 mean in the above query?

Comment: Hi, please check this -> https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-query-parameters

Answer (score 4):

This `?1` indicate a positional parameters is a different practice for define a query parameters to advoid some issue like SQL injection, for example:

- Named parameters:

```
    String statment = "SELECT * from Users WHERE name=:nameParam and role=:roleParam";

    //some code

    query.setString("nameParam", nameValue);

    query.setString("roleParam", roleValue);
```

- Positional parameters:

```
    String statment = "SELECT * from Users WHERE name=?1 and role=?2";
    
    //some code

    query.setString(1, nameValue);

    query.setString(2, roleValue);
```

Comment: Should be query.setString(2, roleValue);